# DXL script to save all advanced filters

Tags: ibm-doors

I have found a script which lets the user write advanced filters; this script can load the current filter from each view but not all filters which exist in the `Filtering` dialog box.  I'd like to be able to extract all of the current advanced filters, even if only as character strings (since I have the tools to parse those strings back into a  `Filter` class object).  If someone knows of a DXL function to retrieve that information, or where the filter strings are stored, I'd appreciate the info. 
Note: no luck chasing this down in the Rational forums.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my hack method.   Basically, there's a few setup and operational lines, anda bunch of filter definitions and combinatorics in the middle.   This does save the defined filter as part of the current View.

```
// copypaste next block into DXL edit window
string viewName = "My_View"
filtering off
// individual items first
Filter head = attribute "_ObjectType" == "Heading"
Filter req = attribute "_ObjectType" == "requirement"
Filter inrev = attribute  "_ReqStatus" == "In Review"
Filter ApprListBob = includes(attribute "_ApprovalList","BobJones")
Filter ApprListMary = includes(attribute "_ApprovalList","MaryContrary")
// now combine as desired. examples shown
// Filter ftwo =  ((head && !freq) || inrev)

Filter foofilt = (head ) || (req  && inrev) //) && ApprListBob
set foofilt
filtering on 
// now write  
addFilter(  foofilt)
set( foofilt)
refresh current       // module...
save view viewName //last arg is viewname
// end of copypaste block
```

For those new to DXL syntax,

&& for AND
|| for OR
!  for NOT

If an attribute can take only one value, use the `attribute "atname" == "value"`
form.  If it can take multiple values (e.g. checklist), use the `includes(attribute "atname", "value")` form.

Comment: I don't agree that this is an answer to your own question. IMHO it is a very inconvenient workaround without any UI that pollutes your module with a bunch of views.

Comment: @KaiK. first of all , it does **not** "pollute...bunch of views" - it uses the **existing** view name.  Next,  it's a workaround, but it is far faster than having to rebuild complicated filters via the builtin GUI.   If you'd like a DXL-based GUI which lets you write the entire filter as text, I don't blame you --- but I"m not sure whether that's even possible.

Comment: I apologize, my comment was a little bit imprudent. Didn't check every line of the snippet. Please excuse. Anyway I don't see how this answers your question "how to get filter definitions from the built-in filter dialog". Of course it is possible to store filters for views, this is one use case of views. No DXL action necessary for that. I agree that your approach is much easier and faster than (re-)coding the filter dialog but it I'm pretty sure that it is possible.

Comment: @KaiK.  no worries -- mostly I wanted to make sure other readers didn't get misdirected.   If /when I figure out a GUI interface I'll post that here as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't expect that there is existing API that solves your issue. One approach could be to recode the filter dialog and add your extra functionality. E.g. you could store the advanced filter list on disk and re-use them from where ever you want.

Comment: That's about it,  I fear.   I took a similar approach:  write up the DXL-based definitions of each atomic filter, then write the combinatorics,  and paste the whole mess into the "Edit DXL" window and execute.   See my answer for the kludge.